# How to change the editor styles for Dart eclipse plugin editor

Tags: dart, dart-eclipse-plugin

I would like to change the style for the default look of the Dart-plugin editor in eclipse IDE. For example I would like to change the colour of comments from green (default) to pale gray. How can I accomplish this in the Dart eclipse plugin. I see how it is done for Java, JavaScript etc but none for Dart.

Comment: Just to make sure, you are *not* talking about the Dart Editor (which is based off Eclipse), but the plugin for actual Eclipse, right?

Comment: Yes. I am referring to the dart-plugin for the eclipse (luna) IDE. I have been using the stand-alone Dart editor but I would like to use Eclipse because of the tools that are available, like the built-in Git.

Comment: Thought so... sorry, not an Eclipse user. :(

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to change the theme manually (the Dart plug-in doesn't have any option to change it automatically, and doesn't support other plug-ins like *Eclipse Color Theme*).

Depending on your OS, these steps might be different, but this worked for me on Linux.

From your Eclipse workspace directory, go to `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings`. There is a file named `com.google.dart.tools.ui.prefs`; open it with your preferred text editor.

In my case, I wanted to use the "Dartboard" theme included in Dart Editor. I copy-pasted the following from the same file in the Dart Editor workspace directory (on my system, found in `~/.dartEditor/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings`) :

```
content_assist_completion_replacement_background=250,250,250
content_assist_completion_replacement_foreground=0,0,0
content_assist_parameters_background=250,250,250
content_assist_parameters_foreground=0,0,0
content_assist_proposals_background=250,250,250
content_assist_proposals_foreground=0,0,0
dart_bracket=96,96,96
dart_comment_task_tag=96,96,96
dart_default=0,0,0
dart_doc_default=96,96,96
dart_doc_keyword=96,96,96
dart_doc_link=96,96,96
dart_doc_tag=96,96,96
dart_keyword=0,0,0
dart_keyword_return=0,0,0
dart_multi_line_comment=96,96,96
dart_multiline_string=103,155,59
dart_operator=0,0,0
dart_single_line_comment=122,122,122
dart_string=103,155,59
glanceColorBackground=251,251,200
glanceSelectedColorBackground=182,214,253
pf_coloring_argument=0,0,0
pf_coloring_assignment=0,0,0
pf_coloring_comment=122,122,122
pf_coloring_key=0,0,0
pf_coloring_value=103,155,59
semanticHighlighting.annotation.color=0,0,0
semanticHighlighting.annotation.enabled=true
semanticHighlighting.builtin.bold=true
semanticHighlighting.builtin.color=0,0,0
semanticHighlighting.builtin.enabled=true
semanticHighlighting.class.color=6,70,167
semanticHighlighting.class.enabled=true
semanticHighlighting.constructor.color=6,70,167
semanticHighlighting.constructor.enabled=true
semanticHighlighting.deprecated.color=0,0,0
semanticHighlighting.deprecated.enabled=true
semanticHighlighting.directive.bold=true
semanticHighlighting.directive.color=1,77,100
semanticHighlighting.directive.enabled=true
semanticHighlighting.dynamicType.color=0,0,0
semanticHighlighting.dynamicType.enabled=true
semanticHighlighting.field.color=135,49,46
semanticHighlighting.field.enabled=true
semanticHighlighting.function.color=0,0,0
semanticHighlighting.function.enabled=true
semanticHighlighting.functionTypeAlias.color=6,70,167
semanticHighlighting.functionTypeAlias.enabled=true
semanticHighlighting.getterDeclaration.color=135,49,46
semanticHighlighting.getterDeclaration.enabled=true
semanticHighlighting.importPrefix.color=0,0,0
semanticHighlighting.importPrefix.enabled=true
semanticHighlighting.inheritedMethodInvocation.color=0,0,0
semanticHighlighting.inheritedMethodInvocation.enabled=true
semanticHighlighting.localVariable.color=0,0,0
semanticHighlighting.localVariable.enabled=true
semanticHighlighting.localVariableDeclaration.color=0,0,0
semanticHighlighting.localVariableDeclaration.enabled=true
semanticHighlighting.method.color=0,0,0
semanticHighlighting.method.enabled=true
semanticHighlighting.methodDeclarationName.bold=true
semanticHighlighting.methodDeclarationName.color=11,91,210
semanticHighlighting.methodDeclarationName.enabled=true
semanticHighlighting.number.color=0,0,0
semanticHighlighting.number.enabled=true
semanticHighlighting.parameterVariable.color=135,49,46
semanticHighlighting.parameterVariable.enabled=true
semanticHighlighting.setterDeclaration.color=135,49,46
semanticHighlighting.setterDeclaration.enabled=true
semanticHighlighting.staticField.color=135,49,46
semanticHighlighting.staticField.enabled=true
semanticHighlighting.staticFinalField.color=85,18,42
semanticHighlighting.staticFinalField.enabled=true
semanticHighlighting.staticMethod.color=0,0,0
semanticHighlighting.staticMethod.enabled=true
semanticHighlighting.staticMethodDeclarationName.bold=true
semanticHighlighting.staticMethodDeclarationName.color=11,91,210
semanticHighlighting.staticMethodDeclarationName.enabled=true
semanticHighlighting.typeArgument.color=3,49,120
semanticHighlighting.typeArgument.enabled=true
semanticHighlighting.typeParameter.color=3,49,120
semanticHighlighting.typeParameter.enabled=true
sourceHoverBackgroundColor=251,251,200
```

This will change the appearance of every Dart source file you open in Eclipse. Then, you can change the colors as you wish.

It's better than that eye-stinging and ugly purple default Eclipse theme... (in my opinion)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=18619) I'm guessing this probably isn't possible right now :-/